# Can Access LocalHost But

Tags: network-protocols

I'm not sure how this website works but I will give it a try.. I am having an issue with my web server..

I have installed Postgres server, and enabled apache, and phpmyadmin. I can access the required default pages in apache by going to localhost & 127.0.0.1. However, when I type my ip address in the web browser like this:  24.1.140.250

I get this: 
**The connection has timed out
The server at 24.1.140.250 is taking too long to respond.
    The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.
    If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer's network connection.
    If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.**

Now, here is the thing.. Other people can see the default page but I cannot. My question is how can I make it so I can see it on my ip address as well. My port's are forwarded. I've checked by going to canyouseeme.org. If anyone can help me I would appreciate it!

Comment: This is the wrong site for this question, try Server Fault or Super User.